# Error while calling a python program from Octave?

Tags: python, octave

I am using Octave for programing and Python for plotting. To make this process automated, I want to call the python script from within Octave. I perfomred a simple test in Octave and got some errors. First, I do not understand what the issue is and ofcourse do not know how to resolve these. This what I typed in Octave ( also, note that temp.py is given at the last)

```
system(['C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe ' 'temp.py'])
```

Error messages:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py:140:
UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization
ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under condition when Gnu OpenMP had
already been loaded by Python process is not assured. Please install mkl-service
package, see http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service
  from . import _distributor_init

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 8, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 138, in <module>
    from . import cbook, rcsetup
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 31, in 
<module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)

ImportError:
IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy c-extensions failed.
- Try uninstalling and reinstalling numpy.
- If you have already done that, then:
  1. Check that you expected to use Python3.7 from "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe",
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy version "1.18.1" you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log
- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.
Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.
Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

ans =  1
```

Also, I have installed anaconda python in my system, the program temp.py is given below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.2)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: It says "Please install mkl-service
package, see http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service". Did you do that?

Comment: Use octave for plotting. Matplotlib is literally a ported version of matlab/octave's plotting functions. And, imo, octave's plots are much nicer than matplotlib's. However, if you insist, I would suggest installing a proper python environment using the official installer, and then put the python executable on your path. Anaconda is usually more for 'bundling' python environments for use in particular contexts. It doesn't sound like you have that issue.